# Iterate through array and swap neighbours

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have a [BIP39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki) passphrase with 24 words to recover my cryptocurrency wallet. Unfortunately, the passphrase doesn't validate (the last word is a checksum). All the words in the passphrase are in the list of available BIP39 words so my first guess is that I mixed up the order of two neighbouring words in the phrase/array.

I wanted to loop through each word in an array, swap it with the neighbouring word, run a function `check(phrase)`, undo the swapping and move to the next word.

Example:

```
initialPhrase = 'wordOne wordTwo wordThree'
firstAttempt = 'wordTwo wordOne wordThree'
secondAttempt = 'wordOne wordThree wordTwo'
```

How can I code this up using JS assuming that I have all words in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code:

> var words = initialPhrase.split(' ');
>
> for(var i=0; i < words.length - 1; ++i){
>
> words[i] = words.splice(i+1, 1, words[i])[0];
>
> var testPhrase = words.join(' '); // your desired phrase
>
> words = initialPhrase.split(' ');
>
> }

Answer (score 1):

Including undo:

```js
function check(phrase) {
  //custom validator code
  var phraseStr = phrase.join(' ');
  console.log(phraseStr);
  if (phraseStr == 'wordOne wordTwo wordFour wordThree') {
    console.log('valid!');
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function getValidPhrase(phrase) {
  for (i=1;i<phrase.length;i++) {
    //swap
    phrase[i] = phrase.splice(i-1, 1, phrase[i])[0];

    if (check(phrase)) {
      return phrase;
    }
    //undo swap
    phrase[i] = phrase.splice(i-1, 1, phrase[i])[0];
  }
  return null;
}

var pp = getValidPhrase(['wordOne', 'wordTwo', 'wordThree', 'wordFour']);
```